# Unable to center 4 divs inside of one div

Tags: html, css

I don't know if i'm half asleep but I cant seem to center align 4 div's, inside of another div.

Here is my jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cwgv4/481/

```
    <body>
    <div id="content">
    <div class="Division"><p>First Division</p></div>
    <div class="Division"><p>Second Division</p></div>
    <div class="Division"><p>Third Division</p></div>
    <div class="Division"><p>Fourth Division</p></div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

The css

```
.Division{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.p{

}
body { 
    marin: auto 0;
    width: 900px;

}
#content {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:left;
    padding:15px;
    border:1px dashed #333;
    background-color:#eee;
    }
```

Comment: Add text-align: center; to #content - http://jsfiddle.net/bhtLubo7/

Comment: `#content {text-align:center;}`  Easy.

Answer (score 0):

add `text-align: center` to `#content`